# Why my code cannot find digits in my String?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to check, if my string contains **ONLY** digits. For this I try:

```
if resultTitles[indexPath.row].rangeOfCharacterFromSet(badCharacters) == nil {
    let badCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
    print("Index: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

It worked, but now it doesn't. It's really strange. What is wrong here?

Comment: could share the `let badCharacters`? :_

Comment: @jycr753 oh sorry, I forgot this line! I've added it!

Answer (score 0):

Does an error appear on the if statement line or the next line? The error is likely due to declaring badCharacters **after** you're using it in the if statement, and because it's a let you can't mutate it if it already exists.

Comment: What are you expecting the results to be and what are the actual results? Perhaps consider posting an [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
if resultTitles[indexPath.row].rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil {
    print("Index: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Alternate solution to check if a String contains only numbers:

```
 CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: yourString))
```

Another Solution:

```
if(Int(yourString!) != nil){
  //String contains only numbers/digits.
}
else {
  // String not contains only numbers.
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the code in the question, although written in a more roundabout way.

Comment: Why not simply `let isNumeric = Int(yourString) != nil`?

Comment: @ArgaPK The check is `string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet.invertedSet) == nil`.  However, I still prefer doing it using `string.range(of: "^\\d*$", options: .regularExpression) != nil`.

Comment: @ArgaPK Because it doesn't answer the question. The question was "what is wrong with the code". You answer is "I do it differently". The question should be closed in the first place because it doesn't provide enough information to answer.

Comment: @Sulthan ok then what about the solution? does the solution i provided is not given answer on "how to check if a string contains digits only"??