# How to check if text contains only numbers?

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried many cases, but none work for me. I tried:

```
if resultTitles[indexPath.row].rangeOfCharacterFromSet(badCharacters) == nil {
    let badCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
    print("Index: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

also tried to

```
if ((resultTitles[0].toInt()) != nil) {
    print("ERROR")
}
```

So, how can I check that my text contains only numbers?

Comment: While converting to int (Option 2), what response are you getting? Have you tried this: https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator

Comment: Can your text can contain multiple numbers, or only one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my code cannot find digits in my String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586045/why-my-code-cannot-find-digits-in-my-string)

Answer (score 117):

I find this solution, in Swift 3, to be cleaner

```
import Foundation

CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: yourString))
```

Comment: Note that this requires import Foundation

Comment: Why your answer is down below here? Why it's not the accepted one? Thanks

Comment: It's an elegant solution, however, if the string is very long,  it will lead to performance issue.

Comment: This code works on Swift 5, too. And `import Foundation` not required in my project.

Answer (score 42):

You just need to check whether the `Set` of the characters of your `String` is **subset** of the `Set` containing the characters from 0 to 9.

```
extension String {
    var isNumeric: Bool {
        guard self.characters.count > 0 else { return false }
        let nums: Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        return Set(self.characters).isSubset(of: nums)
    }
}

"".isNumeric // false
"No numbers here".isNumeric // false
"123".isNumeric // true
"Hello world 123".isNumeric // false
```

Comment: While this probably works in your language, please note that this won't work in languages that use other characters for 0-9 like indic and arabic, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1408239-decimaldigits

Answer (score 18):

We have to check whether every character of the string is a digit or not and string must not be empty.

```
extension String {
   var isNumeric: Bool {
     return !(self.isEmpty) && self.allSatisfy { $0.isNumber }
   }
}
```

**allSatisfy(_ predicate: (Character) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool** is a method which returns a Boolean value indicating whether every element of a sequence satisfies a given predicate.

For reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy

**Example:**

1. let string = "123" string.isNumeric ---- **returns true**
2. let string_One = "1@3" string_One.isNumeric ----  **returns false**

Comment: However, `"㊈⅚".allSatisfy(\.isNumber) // returns true` which is most likely not the intention

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on the fantastic work from Luca above, here is the answer given written by way of Swift 5.

```
extension String {
    var isNumeric: Bool {
        guard self.count > 0 else { return false }
        let nums: Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        return Set(self).isSubset(of: nums)
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer to this question!

Comment: Yes, and allows you to configure for a decimal point also if you need to test for a double

Answer (score 5):

This may help you.

```
 let string  = "536783"
    let num = Int(string);

    if num != nil {
        print("Valid Integer")   
    }
    else {
        print("Not Valid Integer")
    }
```

Comment: in both cases I get "Valid Integer". When I type "123" or "Swift"

Comment: I also tried and getting proper result for "123" is returns "Valid Integer" and "Swift" returns "Not Valid Integer".

Comment: This would overflow when the string is too big.

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you mean by numbers. If you mean 0-9 then you can use this:

```
let numbersSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789")

let textCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "123")

if textCharacterSet.isSubset(of: numbersSet) {
    print("text only contains numbers 0-9")
} else {
    print("text contains invalid characters")
}
```

If you mean all kinds of different ways of specifying numbers then you can use CharacterSet.decimalDigits which contains all kinds of ways of specifying numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
let numbersTest = resultTitles[indexPath.row]
        if let number = Int(numbersTest){
            print(number)//contains onlyy number
        }else{
            print("notnumber")//Not number
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first options works for me in playground. Check it again. Assuming `str = resultTitles[indexPath.row]`

```
func isStringContainsOnlyNumbers(string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet) != nil
}

// Now let's try to use it

let str = "Hello, playground"

if (isStringContainsOnlyNumbers(str)) {
    print("\(str) has illegal characters")  // "Hello, playground has illegal characters"
}
else {
    print("\(str) has only number")
}

let numStr = "332432"

if (isStringContainsOnlyNumbers(numStr)) {
    print("\(numStr) has illegal characters")
}
else {
    print("\(numStr) has only number")   // "332432 has only number\n"
}
```

Comment: what's the point of adding `.invertedSet` instead of making the return `==` instead? Is it better runtime or something?

Comment: To handle cases like that: "123abc". It contains alphabet so it should not pass our check, but if you check if it has numbers, then it will tell you that, yeah, it has numbers:)

Comment: Seems like this fails for "id447919187".

Answer (score 2):

Some of the codes above will work only with Arabic Digits ( 0, 1 , 2 ,...).
However, it won't work with other digits format ( like Hindi one which is used in Arabic countries, ١, ٢ , ٣ , or that one used in Chinese ..)

I have tested the below code ( taken from the codes above with some correction for is Digits with different numbers format ( Chinese, Hindi used in Arabic , ...).

```
extension String {

    var isNumeric : Bool { return CharacterSet(charactersIn: self).isSubset(of: CharacterSet.decimalDigits)
    }

    var isDigits : Bool {
        guard !self.isEmpty else { return false }
        let containsNonNumbers = self.contains { !$0.isNumber }
        return !containsNonNumbers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( [resultTitles[indexPath.row] isMatchedByRegex:@"^(?:|0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?$"] ) {
  //Text is only numeric
}
else
{
  //Text is not only numeric
}
```

Comment: The question is tagged "swift", not "objective-c".

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest `Swift` way in my opinion is this:

```
extension String {
  var isDigits: Bool {
    guard !self.isEmpty else { return false }
    return !self.contains { Int(String($0)) == nil }
  }
}

"123".isDigits // returns true
"12d".isDigits // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

based on 'Cristina De Rito' solution here is a little playgrud routine for checking results, you can add your own `CharacterSet` (swift 5)

```
var arr_IsStringNumberOnly:[String] = ["123", "456.7", "890,1", "1'234", "", "abc", "def3", "xyz 4", "5 äöü"]
for i in 0..<arr_IsStringNumberOnly.count {
    //the code w/o 'nil'
    CharacterSet.init(arrayLiteral: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ",", ".", "'" ).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]))

    //the code with handling 'nil' (nil dosent work in test array)
    //CharacterSet.init(arrayLiteral: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ",", ".", "'" ).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: arr_IsStringNumberOnly ?? "abc")) //if empty assume it's text

    //the code with handling 'nil' (nil dosent work in test array)
    //CharacterSet.init(arrayLiteral: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ",", ".", "'" ).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: arr_IsStringNumberOnly ?? "123")) //if empty assume it's numeric


    //presentation:
    print("arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: \(arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]) \t '\(CharacterSet.init(arrayLiteral: "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ",", ".", "'" ).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i])) )'")

}
```

Presents:

- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: 123    'true'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: 456.7      'true'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: 890,1      'true'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: 1'234      'true'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]:        'true'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: abc    'false'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: def3   'false'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: xyz 4      'false'
- arr_IsStringNumberOnly[i]: 5 äöü      'false'

Comment: Allows you to deal with GroupingSeparator like {,; . ;’} within the displayed String.
Disadvantage. A text containing  a GroupingSeparator only will be interpreted as number.